# Javascript / ES6 parse value from arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to write a generic parser which takes a value, and type and returns label of given value instead.

Currently, this is my code:

```
import a from "../constants/a"
import b from "../constants/b"
import c from "../constants/c"

const find = (value, fromArray) => fromArray.find((term) => term.value === value);
const getLabel = (of, fromArray) => {
    const value = find(of, fromArray);
    return (value && value.label) || 'No info';
};


export default (value, type) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'paymentMethod':
            return getLabel(value, paymentMethods);
        case 'paymentTerm':
            return getLabel(value, paymentTerms);
        case 'dateType':
            return getLabel(value, dateTypes);
        default:
            return 'No info';
    }
}
```

What would be more ES6, faster and concise way to achieve this?

Comment: Your code is fine. Go with it.

Comment: Do you mean `import c from "../constants/c"`?

Comment: @jfriend00 oh yeah, thanks

Comment: @JonasWilms yes it works, but I think it is a repetitive and can be improved in `switch, case` situtation

Comment: This really belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - not on Stackoverflow, the question is not about solving any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of standalone arrays `paymentMethods` etc, you might use an *object* indexed by your `case`s instead, that way you can use object lookup, which is quite concise, instead of `switch`:

```
const obj = {
  paymentMethod: [ < paymentMethodArray> ],
  paymentTerm: [ < paymentTermArray> ],
  dateType: [ < dateTypeArray> ],
};
export default (value, type) => {
  const arr = obj[type];
  return arr
    ? getLabel(value, arr)
    : 'No info';
}
```

Also, not exactly what you were asking about, but your

```
return (value && value.label) || 'No info';
```

is a bit confusing because you're using `&&` to evaluate to a value *other than a boolean* - you might consider using the conditional operator instead:

```
return value
  ? value.label
  : 'No info';
```